# NSJSONSerialization is not woking for IOS 4.3

Tags: json, ios5, ios4, nsjsonserialization

I've a project which was earlier running IOS 5 .I've to make project run on IOS 4.3 .
  When i run the project then i'm getting 2 errors in my following written method. The
  errors that i'm getting is commented . Any possible solution for this .I'm new to Iphone .Kindly help  :)

This method parses the response from the server
   and converts into a model representation for the application.

```
+ (NSArray*) parseResponse:(NSData *) data {
  NSDictionary* json = nil;
Class jsonSerializationClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization");
  if (data) {
  json = [NSJSONSerialization  // error: Use of undeclared identifier  
                              // 'NSJSONSerialization'
            JSONObjectWithData:data
            options:kNilOptions
            error:nil];
  }
   NSLog(@"Total contacts fetched: %u",[json[@"contacts"] count]);
   NSMutableArray *contacts =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   for (NSInteger i=0;i<[json[@"contacts"] count];i++){ //error: Array subscript is not 
                                                     //interger
   NSLog(@"Name %@ ",json[@"contacts"][i][@"lastName"]);
    Contact *aContact=[[Contact alloc]initWithFirstName:json[@"contacts"][i] 
      [@"firstName"]
                                            andLastName:json[@"contacts"][i]
       [@"lastName"]
                                               andEmail:json[@"contacts"][i][@"email"] 
      andPhone:json[@"contacts"][i][@"phone"]];
    [contacts addObject:aContact];
   }
  return contacts;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

NSJSONSerialization is available only in iOS 5.0 and above.

Here is the documentation [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For earlier iOS versions, you could use [SBJsonParser](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) or something else.